# How do I get the leaderboard to grab the right data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building a leaderboard (https://mgo.io/mgo3/leaderboard.php) and I'm having issues making it manually accept data. I want it to grab data from my MySQL database, and allow me to manually go in and enter data which it will in turn display as well. It currently grabs id, and clan names from the clans db.

How do I get it to read data I input from two new 'wins' and 'losses' columns I add in the db it already grabs data from?

Heres my code:

```
<?php

include_once "Log.class.php";
include_once "dbcon.php";

function getLeaders() {
    global $dbh;

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $res = array();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM clans ORDER BY id ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $clan_id = (int) $row['id'];
        $clan_name = $row['name'];

        $res[$clan_id] = array();
        $res[$clan_id]['name'] = $clan_name;
        $res[$clan_id]['rank'] = 0;
        $res[$clan_id]['cp'] = 0;
        $res[$clan_id]['win'] = 0;
        $res[$clan_id]['loss'] = 0;

?>
```

Comment: `SELECT id, name FROM clans ORDER BY id ASC` <- this is your SQL statement....... change this to grab additional columns......

Comment: `SELECT id, name, wins, losses FROM clans ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the fields to your SELECT statement and assign the retrieved values to the appropriate variables:

```
// Add wins & losses here:
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name, wins, losses
                       FROM clans ORDER BY id ASC");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $clan_id = (int) $row['id'];
    $clan_name = $row['name'];

    $res[$clan_id] = array();
    $res[$clan_id]['name'] = $clan_name;
    $res[$clan_id]['rank'] = 0;
    $res[$clan_id]['cp'] = 0;
    $res[$clan_id]['win'] = $row['wins'];    // <<<< and here...
    $res[$clan_id]['loss'] = $row['losses']; // <<<<
```